# Unusual XSLT transformation - structuralization of XML

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I am having some unusual problem. My task is to "structuralize XML". This is an input XML (example):

```
<documents>
  <document>Review</document>
  <document_id>REV#1</document_id>
  <item>List of terms</item>
  <item_id>10</item_id>
  <item_description>Terms used in documents</item_description>
  <item_attribute>Term</item_attribute>
  <item_attribute_name>SA</item_attribute_name>
  <item_attribute_value>Some Attribute</item_attribute_value>
  <item_attribute_name>SOA</item_attribute_name>
  <item_attribute_value>Some Other Attribute</item_attribute_value>

  <document>Interface</document>
  <document_id>AC-163</document_id>
  <item>List of terms</item>
  <item_id>15</item_id>
  <item_description>Another item</item_description>
  <item_attribute>Term</item_attribute>
  <item_attribute_name>Name#1</item_attribute_name>
  <item_attribute_value>Att#1</item_attribute_value>
  <item_attribute_name>Name#2</item_attribute_name>
  <item_attribute_value>Att#2</item_attribute_value>
</documents>
```

What I should do is transform it to following entity structure:

documents 1..* document 1..1 items 1..* item 1..1 attributes 1..* attribute

That means: element 'documents' may include many 'document', 'document' include only one element named 'items', element 'items' may include many elements 'item', etc.

The expected output of the above example is:

```
<documents>
    <document>
        <document_id>REV#1</document_id>
        <items>
            <item>
                <id>10</id>
                <description>Terms used in documents</description>
                <attributes>
                    <attribute>
                        <name>SA</name>
                        <value>Some Attribute</value>
                    </attribute>
                    <attribute>
                        <name>SOA</name>
                        <value>Some Other Attribute</value>
                    </attribute>
                </attributes>
            </item>
        </items>
    </document>
    <document>
        <document_id>AC-163</document_id>
        <items>
            <item>
                <id>15</id>
                <description>Another item</description>
                <attributes>
                    <attribute>
                        <name>Name#1</name>
                        <value>Att#1</value>
                    </attribute>
                    <attribute>
                        <name>Name#2</name>
                        <value>Att#2</value>
                    </attribute>
                </attributes>
            </item>
        </items>
    </document>
</documents>
```

I need some trouble in this task.... May I kindly ask you for any help? This is some unusual to 'structuralize' xml - do you have any ideas?

best regards!

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty easy to achieve with [XSLT grouping](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html) if you're using XSLT 2.0, but just in case you're stuck with XSLT 1.0, here's a XSLT 1.0 compatible solution.

#### Stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="document">
    <!-- Store the unique ID of the current element into a variable. -->
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id()"/>

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::document_id[1]"/>
      <items>
        <!--
        Apply all <item_attribute_name> elements whose first preceding
        <document> sibling is the element that's currently being processed. This
        is to keep from processing *all* of the rest of the
        <item_attribute_name> elements in the document.
        -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::item
          [preceding-sibling::document[1][generate-id() = $id]]"/>
      </items>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id()"/>

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::item_id[1]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::item_description[1]"/>
      <attributes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::item_attribute_name
          [preceding-sibling::item[1][generate-id() = $id]]"/>
      </attributes>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="documents">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item_description">
    <description>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </description>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item_id">
    <id>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </id>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item_attribute_name">
    <attribute>
      <name>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </name>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::item_attribute_value[1]"/>
    </attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item_attribute_value">
    <value>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </value>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item_attribute"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### Input

```
<documents>
  <document>Review</document>
  <document_id>REV#1</document_id>
  <item>List of terms</item>
  <item_id>10</item_id>
  <item_description>Terms used in documents</item_description>
  <item_attribute>Term</item_attribute>
  <item_attribute_name>SA</item_attribute_name>
  <item_attribute_value>Some Attribute</item_attribute_value>
  <item_attribute_name>SOA</item_attribute_name>
  <item_attribute_value>Some Other Attribute</item_attribute_value>

  <document>Interface</document>
  <document_id>AC-163</document_id>
  <item>List of terms</item>
  <item_id>15</item_id>
  <item_description>Another item</item_description>
  <item_attribute>Term</item_attribute>
  <item_attribute_name>Name#1</item_attribute_name>
  <item_attribute_value>Att#1</item_attribute_value>
  <item_attribute_name>Name#2</item_attribute_name>
  <item_attribute_value>Att#2</item_attribute_value>
</documents>
```

#### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<documents>
  <document>
    <document_id>REV#1</document_id>
    <items>
      <item>
        <id>10</id>
        <description>Terms used in documents</description>
        <attributes>
          <attribute>
            <name>SA</name>
            <value>Some Attribute</value>
          </attribute>
          <attribute>
            <name>SOA</name>
            <value>Some Other Attribute</value>
          </attribute>
        </attributes>
      </item>
    </items>
  </document>
  <document>
    <document_id>AC-163</document_id>
    <items>
      <item>
        <id>15</id>
        <description>Another item</description>
        <attributes>
          <attribute>
            <name>Name#1</name>
            <value>Att#1</value>
          </attribute>
          <attribute>
            <name>Name#2</name>
            <value>Att#2</value>
          </attribute>
        </attributes>
      </item>
    </items>
  </document>
</documents>
```

Comment: A good example of the technique I call "sibling recursion". But XSLT 2.0 positional grouping is easier...

Comment: @michael-kay: Thanks! Totally agree that XSLT 2.0 grouping is easier — I just went with XSLT 1.0 because the XSLT version wasn't specified in the question.

Comment: It works, but why did you assume that 'Items' holds ony one 'Item', etc? :(

Comment: I modified my answer to account for multiple following `<item>` siblings before the next `<document>` element.